# How to remove emptyMessage from primefaces TreeTable

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

Is there a way to completely remove it, I don't mean using emptyMessage="" I mean like leaving it completely without it, in the following images I have a treetable which is empty, it works just as a header for the treetable after it.

treetable with default emptyMessage:

[image: treetable with emptyMessage default]

Using emptyMessage="":

[image: using emptyMessage=""]

None of the above is what I want.

I need that greyline that separates the 2 treetable to be gone, this didn't happen in PrimeFaces 3.5, only happening now in 7.0, is there a way? :) in 3.5 you could have a treetable with null value, now it isn't possible, so in managedbean I give it a default value on postconstruct and on the getter also when it is null, but this doesn't matter I think for the result im looking for, just for put you in context of why it didn't happen before.

Comment: Just look at the CSS and customize to make it do what you want.

Comment: @Melloware how do I look at its css mate??

Comment: Well, it is not a microscope, that is for sure. Maybe with a browser developer tool? And your 'partners', they do not know this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comments to your question already hint - you can solve this with some simple CSS and using `emptyMessage=""`. Here is a simple example illustrating  how to do it;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Empty treetable styling</title>
        <style>
            tbody#form\:first_data > tr > td:empty {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="form">
            <p:treeTable id="first" emptyMessage="" value="#{treeBackingBean.root}">
                 <f:facet name="header">First TreeTable</f:facet>
            </p:treeTable>
            <p:treeTable emptyMessage="" value="#{treeBackingBean.root}">
                <f:facet name="header">Second TreeTable</f:facet>
            </p:treeTable>
        </h:form>       
    </h:body>
</html>
```

We take advantage of the `:empty` CSS selector in combination with the fact that `emptyMessage=""` will produce an empty `td`element in the resulting treetable. We then hide the element using `display: none;`.

Just for completeness, here is the backing bean used with this example;

```
@Data
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TreeBackingBean implements Serializable {
    private TreeNode root;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        root = new DefaultTreeNode("Testing", null);
    }
}
```

The resulting treetables produced should look similar to the following image;

[image]
We only style the first treetable here, but as you can see it removes the "empty area" that you are experiencing in your question. For comparison purposes I left the second treetable untouched by any custom styling rules.

The first rendered treetable tree grid (the code generated by PrimeFaces for the first treetable) looks like this - you can also clearly see where the styling rule defined earlier matches;

```
<table role="treegrid">
    <thead id="form:first_head">
        <tr role="row"></tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot></tfoot>
    <tbody id="form:first_data" class="ui-treetable-data ui-widget-content">
        <tr class="ui-widget-content ui-treetable-empty-message">
            <td colspan="0"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Cheers!... maybe a good thing to add the client-side rendered html to, since that seems to be the biggest problem of the OP

Comment: @AdamWaldenberg thanks mate, css is my biggest weakness in programming, im gonna try it tomorrow at work! thanks :)

Comment: @AdamWaldenberg hey brother it worked, just had to figure for like 5 mins that had to change #form for my form id and also first for my treetable id, im such a newb at it hehe

Comment: @BugsForBreakfast Great to hear.